rsync creates directory structure but does not copy the associated files
I am trying to use rsync to copy a folder and its associated sub-folders to a new USB-connected hard drive:
rsync -av /media/foo/EBU402/hdd011 /media/foo/EBU601/hdd011

Some of the sub-folders and files are copied correctly but there are sub-folders that are created but not populated (they do contain files):
/media/foo/EBU402/ps.all/ps/opx.ps/(129 folders) <-- all folders are empty

Diagrammatically:
media -- foo -- EBU402 -- ps.all -- opx.ps +-- Folder001 <-- all folders are empty
                                           +-- Folder002
                                           +-- Folder003
                                           .
                                           .
                                           .
                                           +-- Folder129

fsck on both drives reports that they are clean.
All the files and folders have permissions set to 0777.
rsync returns no errors.
The external drive is attached to a powered USB hub.
There are fewer than 10,000 files to be copied.
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
I am at a loss. This is also very worrisome as rsync to a backup drive is unreliable.
Note added 2024-1013T1028:
I ran rsync with the --stats flag. The output is shown below. The sub-directories that were not populated are now (apparently) properly populated. I am baffled. What I need now is some way of verifying that the files were copies without having to check for the existence of 4 million files.
Number of files: 4,021,174 (reg: 3,823,909, dir: 197,241, link: 24)
Number of created files: 4,021,174 (reg: 3,823,909, dir: 197,241, link: 24)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 3,823,909
Total file size: 1,676,522,777,391 bytes
Total transferred file size: 1,676,522,776,981 bytes
Literal data: 1,676,522,776,981 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 175,014,901
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 1,677,214,012,251
Total bytes received: 74,008,114

sent 1,677,214,012,251 bytes  received 74,008,114 bytes  144,127,864.26 bytes/sec
total size is 1,676,522,777,391  speedup is 1.00


Please run rsync again by adding the --stats option, then Edit the question and copy-paste the output of the command.

You need to use the -r or --recursive option to recurse into directories.

@codlord -r is already applied, by -a: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+-a

a useful tool is LuckyBacup. You can, using a GUI based program, build your your script and then view it, copy it or whatever you wish. https://luckybackup.sourceforge.net/install.html

This could be an artifact of the "slow copy" problem, where your command finishes, but system buffers have not yet been flushed. Does your target device show activity after the rsync finishes?

"What I need now is some way of verifying that the files were copies without having to check for the existence of 4 million files". You can run rsync and provide paths to the source and destination directories, to sync only some sub-folders, like this: rsync -av --stats /media/foo/EBU402/hdd011/ps.all/ps/opx.ps/ /media/foo/EBU601/hdd011/ps.all/ps/opx.ps/ (please check the paths before running the command)

The external USB drive is attached as part of my set-up and remains mounted all the time. This particular system is constantly on so I wouldn't think that "slow copy" would be a problem.
